# Tradução de "I'm not you and you are not me"

Tags: tradução-inglês

Eu entendo que seria:
Eu não sou você e você não é eu.

Eu não sou tu e tu não és eu. Também seria aceitável, a meu ver.

Porém
Eu não sou você e você não sou eu. Estaria errada, pois "você não sou eu" é na verdade "Eu não sou você" e não "You are not me".
Infelizmente, entendo que as pessoas prefiram essa última forma por questões de cacofonia.

Comment: Eu diria que é evitado menos por cacofonia e mais por "é eu" soar errado, inclusive pela reminiscência com o bordão "é nóis".

Comment: "Eu não sou eu" = I am not me. Não vem na frase em inglês. Não entendo a confusào. que aparentemente está acontecendo.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a localização da frase seria: "Eu sou eu, você é você."

Comment: No, that would be: You are you and I am me. Localization is not needed for the translation. It is not the negative of those two utterances.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not you: [Eu] Não sou você

You are not me: Você não é eu.

[image]

Por exemplo:

> Volta às aulas Nesta volta às aulas o entusiasmo não pode faltar. Por
> isso, em trabalho com seus colegas, utilize esta mensagem como ponto
> de reflexão.

> [canção]
> **Eu não sou você Você não é eu**
>
> **Eu não sou você Você não é eu**
> Mas sei muito de mim
> Vivendo com você E você, sabe muito de você vivendo comigo?
> Eu não sou você.
> Você
> não é eu. etc.

[volta as aulas](https://www.construirnoticias.com.br/volta-as-aulas-05/)